# How do I align paragraph text so that it becomes shorter but WIDER?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-onenote

If I copy text from a PDF file or a website that has a narrow width margin, those margin settings are preserved when pasted into Word or Onenote. This is annoying because many websites and PDF's have a narrow-width wall of text and it is innefficent when you have a long vertical wall of text that could have been spreaded out more horizontally to make use of the available space on Word/Onenote page.

For example in this paragraph

> "A lion, he says, can use his prodigious
>
> hunting skills to capture a field mouse with relative ease anytime
>
> he wants, but at the end of the day, no matter how many mice he's
>
> ensnared, he'll still be starving. The moral of the story: Sometimes,
>
> despite the risk and work involved, it's worth our time to go for the
>
> antelope. "

Notice how the paragraph could be made wider if i deleted spaces after "prodigious", "anytime", "he's", "Sometimes," and "the". This would bring each line underneath to the line above it. That means i have to manually delete a space after each of those words to make the paragraph fit a wider margin available.

How can I automate this process? I tried all of the paste options Word/OneNote offers (Keep source formatting, Merge Formatting, Keep Text Only) and none of them make any difference to the margin/alignment of the paragraph. Nor does playing with Center/justified/left/right alignment helps

Comment: @AaronMiller That is severely inappropriate. LMGTFY links do **not** belong on Superuser.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Acknowledged; I've deleted the comment. I'd still strongly suggest the OP do some Googling on the subject, though. There seem to be all manner of methods available.

Comment: @Tim, Are you sure what you are deleting at the end of the line is a space, and not an extra paragraph break? If the later you could do a search and replace for paragraph breaks (^p^p) and replace with just one.

Comment: @Adam Yea it looks like a paragraph or line break. Unfortunately onenote does not have this find&replace tool, and even the onetastic addon macro that has a tool called "search and replace" won't recognize ^p^p. 
The other workaround i have found is use http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php and it can help preserve unwanted replacements. However this tool would be much handier to be inside of onenote.

Answer (score 0):

Use "paste special" and choose "text" instead of "html"

Answer (score 0):

Those are not spaces at the end of the lines.  PDFs use line breaks at the end of each line, so when copying from a PDF those line breaks are also copied.  To automate the the process you can select the text and use Word's ***Find and Replace*** (Ctrl+H) feature to replace "paragraph marks" with spaces.

1. Click the **Find what** field to make it active, and then click **More >>**, **Special**, and **Paragraph Mark** to search for the line breaks copied from the PDF.
2. Click the **Replace with** field and press the *space bar* on your keyboard to indicate that you want to replace each paragraph mark with a space.
3. Click **Replace All**.

[image]